# Adding Fields in Add User page of Liferay

Tags: eclipse

I need to add fields in 'Add User' page of liferay,unable to find which jsp page to override using hook..any one pls help me out..

Liferay->Admin->Control Panel->Add User

Answer (score 0):

For Liferay v.6.1.1 CE:

update categorySections and Categories in `~\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\users_admin\edit_user.jsp`

and put you one `my-custom.jsp` to `~\portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\users_admin\user`